# JSTL custom tag

Tags: jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

How would I write (just a template) for a custom tag with 2 attributes that lets me output a html fragment (a html table) using jstl tag logic, that can be called from my jsp.

Can this be done without writing a java class, which is what I have seen in all the examples.

What I'm trying to acheive is to externalise repeated JSTL logic in my JSPs into a custom tag then pass the dynamic values needed to the tag at run time using the attributes.

Thanks,

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Don't use scriptlets! They're a bad practice and they let business-logic leak into your view layer.

You can create a tag file using JSTL; it's pretty simple. [This](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnama.html) is a good place to start.

An example:

**mytable.tag**:

```
<%@ attribute name="cell1" required="true" type="java.lang.String" description="Text to use in the first cell." %>
<%@ attribute name="cell2" required="false" type="java.lang.String" description="Text to use in the second cell." %>

<table>
 <tr>
  <td id = "cell1">${cell1}</td>
  <td id = "cell2">${cell2}</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Assuming that your tag is in `/WEB-INF/tags`, you can then use it like this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="mystuff" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>

<mystuff:mytable cell1="hello" cell2="world" />
```

Answer (score -3):

Instead of taking a tag approach, on your starting JSP, you can put the output of your condition into a session variable and then use that session variable in all other variables via scriptlets. Something like below:

Starting JSP

```
<% boolean doStuff = isMyConditionTrue ? true : false;
   session.setAttribute("doStuff", doStuff);
%>
```

Other JSPs

```
<% if(session.getAttribute("doStuff") != null && (boolean)session.getAttribute("doStuff")) {
%>
  //do stuff
<% } %>
```

Comment: in my scenario i want to re-use a fragment of my jstl